# gdi+ buffer to file

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

I have written a little program that produces some nice real time full screen patterns and effects.

As an after thought I decided to add a screen grab feature to the program so that hitting Print Screen would cause a still image of the current frame to be saved to disk.

The program uses GDI+ and writes the graphics directly to the form via a manually controlled double buffer. like this:

```
Dim mContext As BufferedGraphicsContext

Dim mbuff As BufferedGraphics
```

.

```
mbuff = mContext.Allocate(Me.CreateGraphics, rec)
```

.

```
mbuff.Graphics.FillRectangle... and other drawing operations.
```

.

```
mbuff.render
```

Is there a simple way to get the information from the form or buffer into a state that I can write it to a jpg or bmp file, that I'm missing?

Thanks